# Global ArrayList variable returning empty

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have an global `ArrayList` called partitions, in my method `getMutableCountryLiveData()` I update this ArrayList. Then in `setUpButton()` I call that same `ArrayList`.  This should work as its an global variable. However, the `ArrayList` returns empty. Any ideas why this is the case? Thanks

Code:

```
public class PlannerResultsFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<Country> cities = new ArrayList<>();
    private MutableLiveData<List<List<Country>>> mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private View view;
    private ArrayList<Integer> days = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<List<Country>> partitions = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        fragmentPlannerResultsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_planner_results,container,false);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planner_results, container, false);

        getMutableCountryLiveData()

        setUpButton();

        return fragmentPlannerResultsBinding.getRoot();
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<List<Country>>> getMutableCountryLiveData() {
        final TriposoAPI userDataService = RetrofitClient.getService();
        Call<InitialResponse> call = userDataService.getPlannerResults(city_input,persona_input,items_input);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<InitialResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<InitialResponse> call, Response<InitialResponse> response) {
                InitialResponse cityResponse = response.body();

                if (cityResponse != null && cityResponse.getResults() != null) {
                    cities = (ArrayList<Country>) cityResponse.getResults();

                    int partitionSize = 2;

                    for (int i=0; i < cities.size(); i += partitionSize) {
                        partitions.add(cities.subList(i, Math.min(i + partitionSize, cities.size())));
                    }

                    mutableLiveData.setValue(partitions);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<InitialResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
        return mutableLiveData;
    }


    public void setUpButton(){

        for (int i = 0; i < partitions.size(); i++){
            days.add(i);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is your response coming after a delay?

Comment: @Sidak yeah partition is set after a delay

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the `ArrayList` returns null"? Do you mean that calling `get()` on it somewhere returns a null value? Or do you mean that it's throwing a `NullPointerException` somewhere?

Comment: @MikeM. to clarify, the array list is initially empty, then in getMutableCountryLiveData() I'm adding to it, so when I use it in setUpButton() after, I'm expecting it to contain values, but it is still empty

Comment: are you sure you are populating it without anyissue??

Comment: Ah, OK, so nothing is null, then; you just have an empty list. That Retrofit operation is asynchronous. Your code does not pause and wait at the `enqueue()` call, but immediately continues to return from the `getMutableCountryLiveData()` method, and then onto the `setUpButton()` call, at which point, the list is still empty. You would need to trigger your button setup from `onResponse()` instead.

Comment: @MikeM. oh okay, makes sense. Have triggered the method in onResponse() and now works fine, thanks!